# How to Transfer the image capture by web cam to google cloud vision api

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, node.js

In this I am capturing the Image from the Webcam.But I fail to transfer the image to the google cloud vision api.I wanna do the text detection also when the capturing the image and image transfer through the api.
Can anybody help out with that problem?
This is Webcam code

```
<script>
    (function() {

        var width = 320; // We will scale the photo width to this
        var height = 0; // This will be computed based on the input stream

        var streaming = false;

        var video = null;
        var canvas = null;
        var photo = null;
        var startbutton = null;
        var data=null;
        
        function startup() {
            video = document.getElementById('video');
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            photo = document.getElementById('photo');
            startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: false
                })
                .then(function(stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
                });

            video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
                if (!streaming) {
                    height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);

                    if (isNaN(height)) {
                        height = width / (4 / 3);
                    }

                    video.setAttribute('width', width);
                    video.setAttribute('height', height);
                    canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                    canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                    streaming = true;
                }
            }, false);

            startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
                takepicture();
                ev.preventDefault();
            }, false);

            clearphoto();
            quickstart()
        }


        function clearphoto() {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            photo.setAttribute('src', data);
        }

        function takepicture() {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            if (width && height) {
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

                data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

                photo.setAttribute('src', data);
            } else {
                clearphoto();
            }
        }

        
        window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
    })();
    </script>
```

I wanna add that code in the webcam portion.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
async function quickstart() {
        process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/home/manu/Cap/Real_Time/VisionAPI_DEMO/ServiceAccountToken.json"

        const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');


        const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

        // Performs text detection on the local file
        const [result] = await client.textDetection("image/test.jpg");
        const detections = result.textAnnotations;
        const [ text, ...others ] = detections
        console.log(`Text: ${ text.description }`);
    } 
quickstart()
```

Comment: And whats the problem?

Comment: When i add the api code in the webcam then webcam stop working.I just wanna know how I can add api code in the webcam script so I can check text in the image that capture by webcam

Comment: `process.env` & `require(...)` are not defined in the browser. These are node.js specific. My guess is to bundle your code with something like webpack or gulp.

Comment: @GoBeyond Is your issue resolve?